# edit django form widget rendering

Tags: python, django, django-forms, jinja2, multi-model-forms

I have a Django form where one of the fields is defined as:

```
widgets = {
    'name': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
}
```

The template renders them in a loop with:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <fieldset class="article-form__field">
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
    </fieldset>
{% endfor %}
```

This is rendered as:

```
<fieldset class="article-form__field">
    <label for="category-name_0">Category:</label>
    <ul id="category-name">
        <li><label for="category-name_0"><input id="category-name_0" name="category-name" type="checkbox" value="GEN" /> General information</label></li>
        <li><label for="category-name_1"><input id="category-name_1" name="category-name" type="checkbox" value="FOO" /> Food and drinks</label></li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```

In short: `<label><input></label>`. However, I would like the output to be `<label></label><input>`.

Is that possible, and if so, how?

Full code is [here](https://gist.github.com/Flobin/4a38e53c9a779ba1de8ec2417dbc2e15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% for field in form %}
    <fieldset class="article-form__field">
    {% if field.name != "category-name" %}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
    {% else %}
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        <ul id={{ field.auto_id }}>
        {% for checkbox in field %}
            <li> 
                <label for="{{ checkbox.id_for_label }}">
                    {{ checkbox.choice_label }}
                </label>
                {{ checkbox.tag }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
    </fieldset>
{% endfor %}
```

- [CheckboxSelectMultiple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple)
- [RadioSelect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect) (how to customize rendering is described here)

Comment: Thanks so much! This solves my issue. (In my example the name is actually "name", but that's another issue.) 

Just one thing, what if I want to do the same with another widget? Or an arbitrary number of widgets? Could I use `{% if field.name != "category-name" and field.name != "another-name" %}`?

Comment: @Flobin Yes, you can. I am not familar with Jinja2, but maybe you can use `{% if field.name not in ['category-name', 'another-name'] %}`.

Comment: Thanks so much Vladimir!